# How do I get rid of this parenting cross in blender?

Tags: objects

[image]

How do I get rid of that weird cross and the weird lines? I understand it's probably parented but I don't know why or how to get rid of it?

Comment: The cross is an Empty which won't show up when rendered and the lines are Relationship lines which show that your objects are parented to that Empty. Again they will not appear when rendered, but you can turn off their visibility by unchecking 'Relationship Lines' on the Viewport Overlay menu.

Comment: thank you! I also figured out a quicker way which is ctrl + p and the options to removing them comes up

Comment: Yes, it is quicker to unparent them, but it was not entirely clear if you just don't want to see the "weird lines" or don't want the objects to be parented at all, since we don't know why there is an empty with objects parented to it, when you don't even know yourself how it got there... so if one day you should want to have objects parented to an empty but do not want to see the lines, follow the instructions by @JohnEason to deactivate them in the _Overlays_. And if you don't want to see the "weird cross", you can turn it off in the _Object Types Visibility_ menu at the top.

Comment: To unparent it's Alt P, not Ctrl P, then Clear and Keep Transformation if you want to make sure that the objects won't move away (to their original location before they were parented)

Comment: To add to the other comments, it's probably been set up that way so that you can move all the objects at once while keeping their relative positions with one another by simply selecting the Empty and moving that.  This method of parenting is very common for models which are made of lots of seperate Objects  but need to be moved as one unit.